# JTable sort on value that isn't displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with multiple columns, one of these columns contain the age of a person, but when it's that persons date of birth than it will be shown as '20 (+1)', therefore this column is from the type string.

This causes problems in sorting the JTable as when you will sort it with the following ages you get this order:
2
21
24
3
34
38
5
60

While I would like to stort it based on the person age value, which is stored as an integer within the persons object, which should get the following order:
2
3
5
21
24
34
38
60

Of course I could remove the '(+1)' part, but that is a nice feature to indicate that the value in that cell has been changed.

Not sure if there is a solution for this problem as I'm probably using the columns 'wrong'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel(table.getModel());
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

TableRowSorter uses java.util.Comparator objects to sort its rows. A class that implements this interface must provide a method called compare that defines how any two objects are compared for the purpose of sorting.

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(s2));
    }
};
```